# How to setup Class Table Inheritance to tables with different ID-columns' names in Doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine, class-table-inheritance

I have a table `person` with `id` as identifier column and a tables `student` with `person_id` as `PRIMARY KEY`. The column `student.person_id` references (`FOREIGN KEY`) the `person.id`.

There are accordingly three classes: An `abstract` class `Person` with a member `id` and its sub-classe `Student` without any "identifying property".

I'm trying to define the [`Class Table Inheritance`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) for this structure:

**`Person`**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Parent
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="person"
 * ),
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 */
abstract class Person
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

**`Student`**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Student
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="student")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Student extends Person
{
}
```

But when I try to retrieve the objects

```
$testRepo = $entityManager->getRepository(Student::class);
$entities = $testRepo->findAll();
```

I'm getting an exception. The Problem is, that Doctrine assumes, the identifying column for the tables `students` to have the name `id` and build a `SELECT` statement like this:

```
SELECT t1.id AS id_2,
       t1.... AS ..._3,
       ...
FROM student t0
INNER JOIN `person` t1 ON t0.id = t1.id
```

instead of

```
SELECT t1.id AS id_2,
       t1.... AS ..._3,
       ...
FROM student t0
INNER JOIN `person` t1 ON t0.person_id = t1.id
```

and runs into the error

```
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 't0.id' in 'on clause'
```

For a new system the simplest and cleanest way might be to rename the `student.person_id` column. But I'm currently migrating an existing system to Doctrine 2 and would like to let so much as possible as it is, so long the migration is not yet completed.

**How to define a Class Table Inheritance in Doctrine 2 by using different column names for the identifier of the parent and the identifier of the child table(-s)?**

Comment: Please put solutions (even if it is only a work-around) in the *answers section*, not in the question. It was correctly removed before, please leave it out. You are free to post it as an answer below.

Answer (score -6):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

Since I urgently needed a solution for this problem, I resolved it (or better: went around) by renaming of the identifier column to `id`.

Comment: It's not a solution. Please remove this.

Comment: @automatix: Your edit to your question indicated that the problem was resolved, and now you have restored it, people will see that and believe that it is resolved to your satisfaction. I recommend you change that update to say that you have a partial solution ("see one of the answers") but that you are seeking something else (and perhaps you could define what that better solution would look like, or why your workaround is not ideal).

Comment: @automatix: it's a work-around *you posted*. It could be a solution that helps others, it belongs in the answers section. Having it posted here does *not* preclude others from posting a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for your edits, @AFriend. I've rolled this one back, since it is part of the posting guidelines to attribute material where the poster is not the author.

Comment: @Afriend: my interpretation of your edits is that they are retaliatory. I do not advise you get into that habit. I am repairing the work of a few hundred authors, so I can assure you I am not targetting you, and I can give you some confidence that we prefer material to be written with some brevity here. A few of your edits on my material were rejected by the community (probably for being too minor). I have rolled back two and accepted two. I am happy to accept good quality edits to my material when they are made in good faith.